# how to avoid overlap of shapes when using d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I am drawing circles by setting a fixed x position but a changing y position. The problem is the circles are overlapping since the radius of each circle is different.

Ideally in theory to solve that I would probably want to get the y position of the previous circle and add the radius of the current circle to it to get the y position of the current circle. Correct me if I am thinking it wrong.

Right now I am doing something like this now

```
var k = 10;

var circleAttributes = circles.attr("cx", '150')
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
        return (k++) * 10;    //this is a very gray area
    })
```

And I am getting an overlap. Ideally I would like to space the circles form each other. Even if the outer edges touch each other I could live with that. How should I approach it?

I am writing a range which i am using to get the radius

```
var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([min, max])
        .range([10, 150]);
```

and simply passing that as the radius like this

```
.attr("r", function(d) { return rScale(d.consumption_gj_);})
```

This is my fiddle

```
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/Vn7mf/27/
```

Comment: How is the radius being determined?

Comment: @-- elsherbini, I just added that. See if that helps. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did a solution here: http://tributary.io/inlet/6283630

The key was to keep track of the sum of the radius of all previous circles. I did that in a `forEach` loop:

```
data.forEach(function(d,i){
  d.radius = rScale(d.consumption_gj_);
  if (i !== 0){
    d.ypos = d.radius*2 + data[i-1].ypos;
  }
  else {
    d.ypos = d.radius*2;
  }
})
```

then, when setting the attributes of the circles you can use your new `d.radius` and `d.ypos`

```
    var circleAttributes = circles.attr("cx", '150')
        .attr("cy", function (d,i) {
            return d.ypos + 5*i;
    })
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius;})
```

Answer (score 2):

**The Charge Property**

The charge in a force layout refers to how nodes in the environment push away from one another or attract one another. Kind of like magnets, nodes have a charge that can be positive (attraction force) or negative (repelling force).

**From the Documentation:**

If charge is specified, sets the charge strength to the specified value. If charge is not specified, returns the current charge strength, which defaults to -30. If charge is a constant, then all nodes have the same charge. Otherwise, if charge is a function, then the function is evaluated for each node (in order), being passed the node and its index, with the this context as the force layout; the function's return value is then used to set each node's charge. The function is evaluated whenever the layout starts.

A negative value results in node repulsion, while a positive value results in node attraction. For graph layout, negative values should be used; for n-body simulation, positive values can be used. All nodes are assumed to be infinitesimal points with equal charge and mass. Charge forces are implemented efficiently via the Barnes–Hut algorithm, computing a quadtree for each tick. Setting the charge force to zero disables computation of the quadtree, which can noticeably improve performance if you do not need n-body forces.

**A good tutorial that will help you see this in action:**

http://vallandingham.me/bubble_charts_in_d3.html

Comment: I don't think @soum is using a force layout at all.

Comment: @Robotsushi--actually I am seriously re thinking of doing this exercise using the force layout

Comment: I had a good experience with it. I would recommend at least playing with it, because it has a great potential.

Comment: @robotsushi/@elsherbini-- I revisited this project after reading what Robotsushi had to say(I could really use a real name :-))..this is what I came up with, thought I should share it with you guys

http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/doitt/energydata/index1.html

Comment: Note, linked article is written in Coffeescript, not Javascript.